# Faster way to export data from Excel 2007 sheet to SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2005, excel, vsto

I have a web application (ASP.NET 3.5) that allows the users to upload their own excel sheet. This sheet contains information about items that needs to be inserted to SQL Server 2005.

I already have this functionality, however, it's very slow (it takes almost 20 minutes to finish the request). I need a better way to handle this problem.

The sheet contains information about an item. These properties will be inserted into multiple tables for example (Books, Authors, Titles ... etc ...).

What I'm currently doing is the following:

1. The user uploads the file
2. The application opens the file
3. Read each row and update the database accordingly.

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Edit: I'm working with 10.000+ rows per sheet.

Comment: Have you thought about using SQL Server Integration Services?

Comment: It did come up while I was searching for a solution on the internets, however, it's way over my league at the moment. I will keep this in mind however, thanks.

Comment: I know that Cells(int,int) is much more performatic than Range. Also try disabling "Recalculations". There are a couple other excel .net libraries that are faster than interop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) Class.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `Microsoft Jet Database Engine` to convert the spreadsheet into a datatable which you can then bulk insert into the database.

Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx) one.

If you are processing Excel 2007 files then you need to use a different provider.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open EXCEL file directly with SQL server with [openrowset](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3331881/OpenRowSource-and-OpenRowSet-in-SQL-Server-2000.htm).

Comment: I'm using Excel > 2007. I don't think the Jet engine works, that's why I'm using `Interop.Excel`.

Comment: Did you try google it, looks like it works also with excel 2007 jou just need right OleDB connector

Comment: Have you tried to save your excel file in 97-2003 format and use OpenRowSet ?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, reading and writing Excel spreadsheets through the interop is slower than molasses. I'm not surprised it's taking so long with how much data you're working with.

To get around creating Excel instances, try talking directly to the spreadsheets. You'll probably notice a factor of magnitude improvement - you might get done in a few seconds now. If you're working with 2007/2010 .xlsx files, I've used [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) before with success. If you accept old .xls files [this](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) looks like a good start but I've never used it before.

Definitely profile your application first though to determine if this is even the trouble spot - I bet it is, but it might be your SQL inserts or something.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I'm currently looking at EPPlus and it looks like what I'm searching for.